# H1-B vs TN visa

Tags: usa, visa, canadian-citizens, h1-visa

As Canadian Citizen I can get TN visa to work in US, but can I get H1-B instead?

What is difference?

Comment: Removed the "better" question to make it answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ye Standard Disclaimer: IANAL

There is a chart available on [TN Visa Bulletin](http://www.tnvisabulletin.com/tn-vs-h-1b-visa-chart/) run by Brian Zuccaro, Esq that shows the major differences but in a nutshell.  Or you can take a look at [Peng & Weber](http://www.greencardlawyers.com/workvisas/TNvisas/TNcomparison.html) page that give you a nutshell version:

> **Comparison of TN and H-1B visa status**
>
> The major advantage of TN status over H-1B status is that TN status may be obtained at the border, and do not require a petition to the Immigration Service (for Canadians).  This advantage does not apply to Mexican citizens, as Mexicans are required to file a Labor Condition Application with the Department of Labor and a petition with the U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Service.  In addition, TN status can theoretically be renewed indefinitely while H-1B status has a limit of 6 years.   TN status is available to some who do not qualify for H-1B status, including those in certain professions that do not require a bachelor’s degree.
>
> On the other hand, if your profession is not listed in the TN occupation list, or you do not meet the requirements specified, you may be able to qualify for an H-1B visa.  TN visa status also does not allow you to use professional experience to show that you have the equivalent of a bachelor’s degree, as you can with the H-1B program.

Comment: how long it usually takes to get H1-B?

Comment: @Alex Depends on whether you have made the cap

Comment: what do you mean? I understand that company, which hires me, send documents to U.S. CITIZENSHIP AND IMMIGRATION SERVICES. If they sent today when should I expect visa? 1 day? 1 week? 1 month?

Comment: @Alex Not the way the process works.  Unlike TN visas H-1s have quotas and application deadline and minimum start dates: http://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/h-1b-specialty-occupation/understanding-h-1b-requirements, http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/h-1b-specialty-occupations-and-fashion-models/h-1b-fiscal-year-fy-2016-cap-season.

Comment: still don't understand. For example I got offer, company applied for visa. Should I pack my things right now for voyage to US or I can relax and take some vacation?

Comment: @Alex Before you can apply for a visa company has to file I-129 which needs to get approved.  Then starting April 1, 2016 you apply for a visa and if you make the quota (unless your job falls under exception) and if all goes well you may be able to start working on Oct 1, 2016.  But consult a lawyer.

Comment: And compare that to TN, where once you get a job offer letter from a company, you can walk up to the border at any time with the relevant documentation in hand and no other approvals required, and they (hopefully) approve your TN on the spot. I have to infer from your question that there is some particular reason why you do not qualify for a TN, and are therefore attempting the much more difficult H1-B route.

Comment: "On top of this TN doesn't seem to provide a path to US permanent residency while H1 does." H1 also does not "provide a path to US permanent residency." To get a path to permanent residency, you need to be voluntarily petitioned by an employer or family member, etc. Someone can be petitioned in any status, H1, TN, F1, etc. or even in no status and not in the US.

Comment: @user102008 Hence a suggestion to edit the answer.